# Does Zada, Hedron Grinder work with Soul's Fire and other similar instants?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Zada, Hedron Grinder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zada%2C%20Hedron%20Grinder) work with

- [Fall of the Hammer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fall%20of%20the%20Hammer)
- [Soul's Fire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=174951)
- or [Tail Slash](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tail%20Slash)?

Would it spread to the other creatures? Does [Soul's Fire's](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=174951) ability to target a player change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it would not.

Zada:

> Whenever you cast an instant or sorcery spell that targets only Zada, Hedron Grinder, copy that spell for each other creature you control that the spell could target. Each copy targets a different one of those creatures.

Fall of the Hammer:

> Target creature you control deals damage equal to its power to another target creature.

Since there are two instances of the word "target" (and Zada can't be both), Zada is not the only target.

*I suppose Soul's Fire could target Zada herself, so each creature you control would deal damage to itself*

Comment: Soul's Fire can't let a creature hit itself; "another target creature." Tail Slash will though.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Uh, I think you have those backwards. I just checked Gatherer.

Comment: Yeah, I noted that after the fact. Tail slash doesn't work, because "target creature you don't control." Soul's Fire will actually work; Target Zada with both options, and then change the second target for the copies to the player. Sure, Zada self-destructs, but it could be a fair bit of damage.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I'm pretty sure the copies can't change the target to the player, since Zada says to change the (single) target to each other creature you control. So, each creature would be targeted by a copy and deal damage to itself (just like Zada)

Comment: There is a ruling on Zada that addresses this: *"8/25/2015 If you cast an instant or sorcery spell that has multiple targets, but it’s targeting only Zada with all of them, Zada’s ability will trigger. The copies will similarly each be targeting only one of your other creatures. You can’t change any of the copy’s targets to other creatures."*